# Dimension of the set of self-adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out what the dimension of the set of self-adjoint operators on V would be, or in more concrete terms:

Let $dim V =n$. Let $S(V)$ denote the set of self-adjoint linear operators on V. What is its dimension?

The only thing I know that somewhat resembles this might be that $dim L(V) = (dim V)^2$ but I'm not sure how I might be able to apply that to this problem.

Any tips or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Also, V is a finite dimensional inner product (or Hermitian) space.

Comment: The answer depends on the context: is $V$ a euclidean space or is it a hermitian space?

Comment: As in @OlivierBégassat's comment, what field is $V$ a vector space over?  What specific equation does the operator satisfy?  (I think I know, but it will be instructive for you to write it down explicitly.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention its a hermitian space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use matrix representations to figure out the answer. Let $\mathcal B$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$, and let $u\in\mathrm{End}_{\Bbb C}(V)$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Then $u$ is selfadjoint iff its matrix in the basis $\mathcal B$ is hermitian i.e. $$u\text{ is selfadjoint iff }^t\overline{\mathrm{Mat}(u,\mathcal B)}=\mathrm{Mat}(u,\mathcal B).$$ 
What is the (real) dimension of the subspace of hermitian matrices $H_n\subset M_n(\Bbb C)$? Consider a matrix $(u_{ij})\in  M_n(\Bbb C)$: it is hermitian iff for all $i,j\in\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace,~\overline{u_{ji}}=u_{ij}$. You can thus choose the upper coefficients ($i<j$) freely in $\Bbb C$ , the diagonal coefficients $(i=j$) have to be real but can be chosen arbitrarily, and the coefficients below the diagonal ($i>j$) are completely determined by those above the diagonal. Therefore the real dimension of $H_n$ is $2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=n^2$.

Comment: I know that the set of self-adjoint operators has a diagonal matrix i.e. $S(V)$ would be the set of all diagonal matrices because in order to be self adjoint, T must commute with itself. I guess I'm just not sure how to think of that in terms of dimension.

Comment: @KevinLee self adjoint operators are diagonalisable, but not in any orthonormal basis. The basis we chose at the get go will certainly not diagonalize all hermitian operators. So there are more than just the diagonal matrices. Also every operator commutes with itself, self adjoint or not ^^

Comment: Because each $T \in S(V)$ has a diagonal representation, it has $n$ eigenvalues corresponding to $n$ eigenvectors that form a basis of V. So would the dimension of $S(V)$ just be $n$?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just one question though, if the coefficients below the diagonal automatically follow from the coefficients above, then why isn't the dimension for those just $n(n-1)/2$?

Comment: There are indeed $n(n-1)/2$  coefficients to choose, but you choose them $\underline{\text{in }\Bbb C}$! That means you have to choose twice as many real numbers (the real and imaginary parts). The set of all herminitan operators (or matrices) is _not_ a complex subspace, but merely a _real_ subspace!